# Why can't fastapi bring dependency

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi

```
def b():
    return str("bb")


def a(call_b=Depends(b)):
    print(call_b)
    return str("aa")


@router.get("/")
def dep_test(
    call_a: Annotated[str, Depends(a)]
):
    return call_a
```

In the above example, we can see that the print(call_b) result of the a function is bb and thus the dependency is well executed.

```
def b():
    return str("bb")


def a(call_b=Depends(b)):
    print(call_b)
    return str("aa")


@router.get("/")
def dep_test():
    call_a = a()
    return call_a
```

However, in the example above, we can see that the result of print(call_b) is Depends(b), and function b is not executed.

What's the reason?

My hypothesis is that the dependence of the called function doesn't work.

Comment: Dependencies are only resolved when they're part of the controller argument hierarchy - they do nothing (except give you a `Depends` object) when called directly. If you're going to call the function directly, you can just give the function the dependency right there - there is no need for `Depends` in that context. Depends is useful for "resolve this later" in the context of a web request.